# Converting values of the index of a multi-index dataframe to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-index dataframe (with indices `Date` and `Company`) `df` below:

```
                                Amount
Date      Company               
2019-10-01   BoA              3.924454e+09
             Starfirst        1.346442e+04
             Republic         7.006446e+06
2019-11-01   BoA              2.176354e+09
             Starfirst        1.287342e+04
             Republic         3.545446e+06
```

I want to convert `df` to the below (where the `Company` index is converted into columns, where `Amount` is the values and `Date` remains as an index):

```
                BoA            Starfirst          Republic
Date                      
2019-10-01  3.924454e+09       1.346442e+04       7.006446e+06
2019-11-01  2.176354e+09       1.287342e+04       3.545446e+06
```

I've been trying to do this but haven't really got very far.

Comment: Straight-away application of `pivot_table`.. `df.reset_index().pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Company', values='Amount')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unstack` to unstack the inner most index level.

```
df['Amount'].unstack()
```

Output:

```
Company              BoA   Republic  Starfirst
Date                                          
2019-10-01  3.924454e+09  7006446.0   13464.42
2019-11-01  2.176354e+09  3545446.0   12873.42
```